# Show Gtk Spinner while function running only

Tags: python, pygtk, python-multithreading

I want to show Gtk spinner widget only while my function is running. For example:

```
[...]

self.spinner.hide() # hide spinner at startup

self.my_function(input) # run function

def my_function(self, input)
    self.spinner.show() # show spinner when function running
    # do something here that takes long time
    self.spinner.hide() # hide spinner when the process is complete
    return output
```

I'm using this but spinner doesn't appear while my_function is running, on top of it the window gets dark as an unresponsive window.
How should I use spinner and prevent an unresponsive window?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window become dark because of main loop is locked by `my_function`.

Try to call your method asynchronous. It can be implemented with gobject or gdk threads. This example with python threads.

Many prints to describe order of functions:

```
import threading

class Thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,callback,*args,**kwargs):
        self.__callback = callback
        threading.Thread.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
    def run(self):
        try:
            if self.__target:
                print('thread')
                _self = self.__kwargs.get('self',self.__args[0])
                self.__callback(_self, self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs))
        finally:
            # Avoid a refcycle if the thread is running a function with
            # an argument that has a member that points to the thread.
            del self.__target, self.__args, self.__kwargs        

def background(callback):
    print('background')
    def wrapper(fun):
        print('wrapper')
        def inner(*args,**kwargs):
            print('inner')
            Thread(callback=callback,target=fun,args=args,kwargs=kwargs).start()
        return inner
    return wrapper

def spinner(fun):
    def inner(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.show()
        result = fun(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.hide()
        return result
    return inner


def spinner_hide(fun):
    def inner(self,*args,**kwargs):
        result = fun(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.hide()
        return result
    return inner

def spinner_show(fun):
    def inner(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.show()
        result = fun(self,*args,**kwargs)
        return result
    return inner


class A(object):
    @spinner_hide
    def my_function_callback(self,data):
        print('callback')
        print(data)
    @spinner_show
    @background(my_function_callback)
    def my_function(self, input):
        # do something here that takes long time
        print(input)
        output=input
        return output

    def show(self): print('showed')
    def hide(self): print('hidden')

a=A()
a.my_function('gogo')
```

Result of running sample with IDLE

```
background
wrapper
showed
inner
thread
>>> 
gogo
callback
gogo
hidden
```

`>>>` means that main thread becomes IDLE, output after it is background.

Comment: @eri lots of thanks for your answer! I'm not very experienced about python. I have added codes in your answer to my code but it doesn't seem to work :( maybe I'm doing something wrong. This is the code: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76369534/Threading When I run the code and press rotate_button The spinner doesnt appear and image doesnt rotate

Comment: When I click the rotate_button `showed
inner
thread
` appears in terminal and if I close the main window ` Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_label_set_text: assertion `GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
callback
None
hidden
` appears in terminal. Thanks.

Comment: @mnrl your mainloop is `gobject.mainloop` ? it need some magic. `gobject.threads_init()` before `mainloop = gobject.MainLoop()`

Comment: @eri, unfortunately I have no idea about my mainloop. I'm using Canonical Quickly create ubuntu application template. It  creates a template folder in my home folder and there are bin, data, help, turuncu (turuncu is the name of my app), turuncu-lib folders in template folder. I write codes into ~/turuncu/turuncu/TuruncuWindow.py. The /bin/turuncu script launches the application. This is the TuruncuWindow.py: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76369534/TuruncuWindow.py

Comment: And this is /bin/turuncu: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76369534/turuncu I think `import turuncu
turuncu.main()` in /bin/turuncu launches the application. Where should i add `gobject.threads_init()`? Please forgive my ignorance. Thanks again.

Comment: insert `import gobject; gobject.threads_init()` before or inside `turuncu.main()`

Comment: @eri Thank you infinitely!! Adding `gobject.threads_init()` works perfectly. Thank you again for your patience and answers :)

Answer (score 1):

If mainloop is gobject.MainLoop() is better way to use gobject threads.
If Qt - use Qt.

This decorator use `gobject.idle_add` to make function async., but has no callback

```
def async(func):
    """Make a function mainloop friendly. the function will be called at the
    next mainloop idle state."""
    def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
        def async_function():
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            return False
        gobject.idle_add(async_function)
    return new_function
```

Implement calling callback in your function instead of `return` or pass it to decorator as in `def background(callback):...`